# Zend Framwork OR operator use

Tags: zend-framework

I am using

```
$where->equalTo('dailyshifthr.thrs', 0);
$where->equalTo('dailyshifthr.thrsA', 0);
```

I need these two condition in OR not AND condition. Help me.

Comment: Are you using ZF1 or 2 / 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `or` predicate, like:

```php
$where->or->equalTo('dailyshifthr.thrs', 0);
$where->or->equalTo('dailyshifthr.thrsA', 0);
```

If you want to nest these two conditions with others, like

```sql
SELECT *
from your_table
where field_a = 1
and (dailyshifthr.thrs = 0 or dailyshifthr.thrsA = 0)
```

Then you must use the `nest` predicate:

```php
$where->equalTo('field_a', 1);
$nest = $where->nest;
$nest->or->equalTo('dailyshifthr.thrs', 0);
$nest->or->equalTo('dailyshifthr.thrsA', 0);
```